# How to read an extension .proto file (textformat.merge) with old code?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

My question is related with the C# implementation of the google protocol buffers (protobuf-csharp-port, by jon skeet, great job!)

I am experiencing troubles with the extensions: let's say I wrote:

- "transport_file.proto" with a "transport message" and some code to
  deal with it "code_old".
- and I wrote an extension of the transport message on
  "Mytransport.proto" file, and new code to read it "code_new".

I'm trying to read a new message (from MyTransport.proto) with the    code_old expecting to ignore the extension, but I get an exception in the merge method from TextFormat: "transport" has no field named "whatever_new_field"

```
Transport.Builder myAppConfigB = new Transport.Builder();
System.IO.StreamReader fich = System.IO.File.OpenText("protocolBus.App.cfg");
TextFormat.Merge(fich.ReadToEnd(),myAppConfigB);
fich.Close();
```

new extended file looks like:

```
...
  Transport 
  { 
     TransportName: "K6Server_0"
     DllImport: "protocolBus.Transports.CentralServer"
     TransportClass: "K6Server"
     K6ServerParams
     {
        K6Server { host: "85.51.11.23" port: 40069 }
        Service: "TZinTalk"
        ...
     }
  }
...
```

while the old one, not extended:

```
...
  Transport 
  { 
     TransportName: "K6Server_0"
     DllImport: "Default"
     TransportClass: "Multicast"
  }
...
```

The whole idea is to use the text based protocol buffer as a config file in which I write some params, and based on one of those I load and assembly (which will read the whole message with the new extension (params to initialize the object).

**Any idea?** (it is a desperate question :D )

I'm using MSVC# 2008Express edition, protobuf-csharp-port version 0.9.1 (someday I'll upgrade everything).

THANKS in advance.

---

I'm working on a non centrilized Publish-Subscribe framework of messages (for any written message in a proto file I auto create a Publish and a Subscriber class) with different transports. By the default I use multicast, but broadcast and a "*UDP star*" are also included. I let the extension mechanism to let people add new transports with its owm config params that should be read by my main code_old (just to load the assembly) and let the new transport (.dll) read it again (fully).
Curious? the previous, almost functional, version is in http://protocolbus.casessite.org

**Update 1**

Extended types in text format are enclosed in brackets (good to know, I was not aware of it :D ) so I should have written:

```
 [K6ServerParams]
 {
    K6Server { host: "85.51.11.23" port: 40069 }
    Service: "TZinTalk"
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol buffers are designed to be backwards and forwards compatible when using their *binary* format, but certainly the current code doesn't expect to parse the *text* format with unknown fields. It could potentially be changed to do that, but I'd want to check with the Java code to try to retain parity with that.

Is there any reason you're not using the binary representation to start with? That's the normal intended usage, and the one where the vast majority of the work has gone in. (Having said which, it all seems a bit of a blur after this long away from the code...)

Comment: Wow man, I did not expect an answer so soon! I appreciate it. thanks for the answer. It was driven me crazy, and I thoght I was doing something wrong ... well I guess I'll have to do it some other way. THANKS again!    I use the binary version when I send packages in the net, and It is perfect for it, but for config I prefer the text version (no man, no xml files for config, much more readable the proto version).

Comment: @chasques: If you look at the latest version, we have some JSON support which you may find even more readable than the text formatting support. That *may* support unknown fields - I'm not sure offhand.

Comment: That could be a good reason for updating to the new version. I was thinking to use another file with the new params (the extended params of the proto) but the json solution seems to be more elegant. I'll check it up. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, just a few lines to add some light into this matter: I did update your library, It was much easier than I thought, and I did try to use the JSON formatter JsonFormatReader with the same results. So, no more excuses to be lazy: I've been digging into code and I have come to some conclusions:

1.- C# version (and, I guess, java version too): throws an exception in case the extension is not registered or no registry exists at all!!!

Comment: 2.- C++ version: in the case no extension is found (no extension or no registry) returns false and continue parsing the message, after that,  uses a log or a errorcollector to inform (ReportError), but not stopping the parser (repeating the error/log notification  for every field in the extension (not very sure of this)). So in this case it is possible to read a text formatted message with unknown extensions.

I'm trying to modify the TextFormat.cs with a "n~apa" (Spanish word for an easy but not good engineering solution) to make my private functionality. Thanks again.

Comment: @chasques: Cool - glad you've made progress on this; sorry not to have been able to help any more myself.